# If statement using Pandas Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, if-statement

I am trying to pass an "if statement" on an Excel file if certain characters exist in 2 different columns using pandas. There are no errors that occur when executing the code, but the code does not perform any of it's tasks. Here is the code I have so far:

```
def filter_getColumns2(y):
if r'[!|@|#|$|%|^|&|*]' in y['zonename']:
    y['zonename'] = y['zonename'].map(lambda x: re.sub(r'[!|@|#|$|%|&|*]', '', str(x)))
    return y
elif "  " in y['polygonstring']:
    for r, map in y.items():
        y['polygonstring'] = [re.sub(' +', ' ', e) for e in y['polygonstring']]
        y['polygonstring'] = [re.sub(' ,', ', ', e) for e in y['polygonstring']]
        y['polygonstring'] = y['polygonstring'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip(' '))
    return y
else:   
    return y
```

The code executes perfectly without the if statements, but I would just like to add the if statements to better the code.
Thanks in advance, any thoughts or ideas is helpful!

Here is the remainder of my code calling my methods:

```
def create_csv(df3):
df3.to_csv('test.csv', sep=';', index=False, header=False) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sheet = excelFileReader(file_path)
    filter_columns = filter_getColumns(sheet)
    filter_columns2 = filter_getColumns2(filter_columns)
    create_csv(filter_columns2)
```

Comment: Maybe you simply need to escape special char of your if condition:
[\!\@\|\#\$\%\^\&\\*] you can also try your regex at https://regex101.com/

Comment: Are you sure that you need `if-elif-else`? My hunch is that there should be 2 different `if` since columns would generally be independent.

Comment: Hmm I will try it, but even when I tried putting one column in an if statement it still would not execute? @Peaceful

Comment: @Destrif What do you mean by "escape" my special char on my if condition?

Comment: Can you show me how you are actually calling this function?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like a case for any if-else logic. You can use pandas str accessor methods to do all the processing for you.

```
y['zonename'] = y['zonename'].str.replace('[!|@|#|$|%|&|*]', '')
y['polygonstring'] = y['polygonstring'].str.replace(' +', ' ')
y['polygonstring'] = y['polygonstring'].str.replace(' ,', ', ').str.lstrip()
```

Comment: Ahh okay thank you for your help! Im still new at this btw! I tried to upvote your answer but it wont let me...

Comment: If this really did work then accept the answer by clicking the check mark underneath the upvote/downvote area.